# Why can't I call system functions in R that clearly work in my terminal?

Tags: r, system

I am trying to call system functions in R. I am using a mac. If I pass a built-in function (e.g. ln), it works no problem:

```
command <- "ls"
cat(command, "\n")
try(system(command))
```

I get a list of the directory.

However, if I install functions from third parties (e.g. binaries), it doesn't work (even if it works in the terminal).

```
command <- "bedtools ..."
cat(command, "\n")
try(system(command))
```

I get the following error:

```
sh: bedtool..:command not found
```

Do you think it's a PATH problem?

Thank you!

Comment: do you realize that your `command` input doesn't match your error message

Comment: It can't be a PATH problem, if it works from the CL. Unfortunately you don't give a reproducible example and it's hard to go from here.

Comment: @rawr Hi! It's another typo. Sorry.

Comment: @user2472704 so does `system2('bedtools')` work or not

Comment: @rawr It doesn't. :(

Comment: @It's funny because if I open RStudio where the function's binaries are located (e.g. open -a RStudio), it works no problem.

Answer (score 5):

Considered for sure that you 'installed' the command (it exists in a bin somewhere) and after reading yout comment:

> if I open RStudio where the function's binaries are located (e.g. open -a RStudio), it works no problem.

I guess that it is a PATH problem indeed. A possible fix would be:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "/the/bin/folder/of/bedtools", sep=":"))
```

Comment: Curious why R still, years later, does not pull paths from *bashrc* or *bash_profile*...

Answer (score 1):

Where is your bedtools saved? i.e. what is the output from

```
which bedtools
```

If it isn't in your

```
usr/bin
```

then the system command gives that error. Save betools there and it should work.

from the system help file it suggests trying the

```
Sys.which
```

command on your shell input first to see if it will work in system.

Comment: @user2472704, was this any help?