# Call system() function in R to run bash script

Tags: r, linux, bash, system, youtube-dl

I am trying to run a bash command through my RStudio session.
I have installed the ***youtube-dl*** in my Linux.
But when I run from RStudio the command:

```
system("youtube-dl -o test_video.avi https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2CCrUwc3JqA", intern = TRUE)
```

It gives me below error:

> sh: 1: youtube-dl: not found Error in system("youtube-dl -o
>   test_video.avi https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2CCrUwc3JqA",  :
>   error in running command

This looks like an error similar to this post:
[Why can't I call system functions in R that clearly work in my terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065564/why-cant-i-call-system-functions-in-r-that-clearly-work-in-my-terminal)

They suggest to copy ***youtube-dl*** in `/usr/bin` so I did:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl /usr/bin
```

But this did not change anything and I still got the same error.
Help much appreciated!

Comment: hey, be careful about doing sudo commands.. it might mess things up.. you can do "which youtube-dl" in terminal, this gives you the path, and call that in R

Comment: I just ran `which youtube-dl` that gave me `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl` - So I ran `system("/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -o test_video.avi https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2CCrUwc3JqA", intern = TRUE)` but still got same error.

Comment: I just tried it on a linux.. don't see that error.. can you ls -lh /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl on linux and see whether that file is executable?

Comment: I think you are right that might be a permission issue (not having enough permission from my RStudio terminal). The output is `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.7M Jan 29 14:24 /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`

Comment: it's executable and readable by all, so that's fine... I really have no clue, because it worked on my linux.. unless, you cannot access /usr/local/bin/ from R

Comment: Just to clarify, when I do `youtube-dl -o test_video.avi https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2CCrUwc3JqA` from my linux terminal it works fine. But the issue is when I try to run it from RStudio.